# How to calculate the minimum speed for two objects to collide?

Tags: lua, game-physics

The title might not be the most descriptive ever, but my question is:

***How to calculate the minimum speed needed for two objects to collide, not bounce?***

Basically, I'm making a physics engine, and this question has been around my head for a while.

So, basically, what I need, is the method to calculate the minimum speed object A needs to achieve so when it collides with object B, instead of having their cores melting into one, they'd bounce.

Maybe this number is a constant?

Does it depend on the "bounceability" of the object?

I do know how to make the objects bounce, and all that, but I've got no idea how to get that minimum velocity.

Also, I need the maximum speed two objects can bounce when colliding.

Also, if you can, mind if the speed is in m/s (meters per second)? That'd be nice. But I'm fine with any other unit.

BTW, this is made in lua

Help is appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Comment: What's going on in your physics system that "having their cores melting into one" is a possibility when collision happens?

Comment: I would not play a game with a “physics” engine as weird as what you describe.  That's not how physics works.

Comment: Did you read about particular physics engines? you may want to check Unity3D Physics Chapter

Comment: This minimal velocity depends on "adhesiveness" of objects.  Usually objects never melting into one in computer games (unless one object is catching and eating another).  But it sounds interesting.  I'd try to play it :-)

Comment: Look up *coefficient of restitution*. There are simple 1D example problems which may be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Start here: [The Nature of Code](https://natureofcode.com) - by far, the best from-square-one introduction to coding a physics library. All written using Processing, but easily ported to Lua (I’ve done just that) and other languages.